# Moments of $\text{exp}(-|x|^{1/2})$

Tags: distributions, moments, integral, moment-generating-function

I'm supposed to show that all of the moments of the density $\text{exp}(-|x|^{1/2})$ are finite.

I'm not convinced this is true though. The $p$th moment is
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X^p] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty  x^p \text{exp}(-|x|^{1/2}) dx 
\\
&= - \int_0^\infty x^p e^u x^{1/2}dx
\\
&=\int_0^\infty u^{2p+1} e^u du
\end{align*}

where the second equality comes from u-substitution with $u = -x^{1/2}$, $du = -1/2 x^{-1/2}dx$, and the fact that the integrand is even (so that we consider the range $0$ to $\infty$).

This last integral is infinite since I believe that $\int_0^\infty u^p e^u du = \infty$ for any $p> 1$.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get by substitution (for even p) $\int_0^\infty u^{2p+1} e^{-u} du$, which is a Gamma function

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen oh.... so you let $u = x^{1/2}$? This would make sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that the factor necessary to make this a density function on the real line is $1/4$. So
\begin{align}
   \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^p e^{- |x|^{1/2}}/4 \; dx = \\
   \frac14 \int_0^\infty \left[ (-1)^p+1\right] u^p e^{-u^{1/2}} \; du = \\ \begin{cases} 0, \text{odd $p$} \\
          \int_0^\infty u^{2p+1} e^{-u}\; du, \text{even $p$}
    \end{cases} =\\
\begin{cases} 0, \text{odd $p$} \\
              (2p+1)!, \text{even $p$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
so is clearly finite for all positive integers $p$. The integrations above are done by successive substitutions. The last equality is by the [definition of the Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), and the well-known equality $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$, which can be proved by induction.

Comment: Perfect thank you! Could you explain why $\int_0^\infty u^{2p+1} e^{-u} du = (2p+1)!$?